# How can I declare the array chain of type node inside main function and pass it as an argument through other functions?

Tags: c, data-structures, hash

I'm trying to implement chaining(hash). I don' want to declare `node *chain[size]` globally and wanted it to declare it in main and pass it as argument through functions. For that I modified the code to the below one:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define size 10

typedef struct hashNode
{
    int data;
    struct hashNode *next;
} node;

void insert(node *chain, int data)
{
    node *baby = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    baby->data = data;
    baby->next = NULL;
    
    int key = data % size;
    if(chain[key]==NULL)
        chain[key] = baby;
    
    else
    {
        baby->next = chain[key];
        chain[key] = baby;
    }
}

int main()
{
    
    node *chain[size];
    
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        chain[i] = NULL;
    
    insert(chain, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The code gives multiple errors:

```
chaining.c: In function ‘insert’:
chaining.c:21:15: error: invalid operands to binary == (have ‘node’ {aka ‘struct hashNode’} and ‘void *’)
   21 |  if(chain[key]==NULL)
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~^~
      |          |
      |          node {aka struct hashNode}
chaining.c:22:16: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node’ {aka ‘struct hashNode’} from type ‘node *’ {aka ‘struct hashNode *’}
   22 |   chain[key] = baby;
      |                ^~~~
chaining.c:27:16: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct hashNode *’ from type ‘node’ {aka ‘struct hashNode’}
   27 |   baby->next = chain[key];
      |                ^~~~~
chaining.c:28:16: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘node’ {aka ‘struct hashNode’} from type ‘node *’ {aka ‘struct hashNode *’}
   28 |   chain[key] = baby;
```

However, if I declare the array chain globally just after the structure, the same code works perfectly:

```
typedef struct hashNode
{
    int data;
    struct hashNode *next;
} node;

node *chain[size];
```

Comment: Change `void insert(node *chain, int data)` to `void insert(node **chain, int data)`

Comment: Realize that `node *chain[]` is of type `node **` as UnholySheep suggested.

Comment: @JoopEggen : It worked. Cud you plz explain why is it so - node *chain[] is of type node ** ?

Comment: `X[]` is the same as `X*`. Everything is a pointer in C, A pointer to an array is a pointer to a pointer of an array element.

Comment: @JoopEggen, No. The value of array is implicitly transformed to a pointer to array's first element.

Comment: @tstanisl In Pascal an array (array value) are bytes the size of a multiple of (padded) elements. You can pass that array value as parameter - passed with the size). In C an array is the address of the content bytes., the address of the first element. That address, the pointer is passed. _I think we have just a different terminology.._

Comment: @JoopEggen, if arrays were pointers then `sizeof arr` would always return the same value. No, arrays are not pointers. Only values of arrays becomes pointers.

Comment: @tstanisl you are right, good argument. The compiler has its metadata on arrays. Still `char x[] = array;` - without bounds - looses info; sizeof is not passed as real data.

Comment: @JoopEggen, the "metadata" is the *type* of an object. For example a type `"ab"` is `char[3]` so `sizeof "ab"` is 3. The dimensions of an array are bound to its type. When `array` object is used in an expression (but not for all expressions!) then its *value* is taken. In C, a value of an array is implicitly transformed to a pointer. That is why cannot assign to an array because right-hand-side expression becomes a pointer and it is not possible to assign `char*` to `char[]` because they are completely different types.